# Extract value of parameter from GET URL, pass it to header and pass to the second url

Tags: jmeter, load

I am stuck with the following issue.

My example:

1. I have GET url [www.example.com/login?id=some](http://www.example.com/login?id=some) value
2. This GET url has headers and one of them is Referer [www.example.com/login?goto=should](http://www.example.com/login?goto=should) be value from GET url
3. After that, url from header should be opened with value that we should obtain from id parameter and pass it to goto parameter.

Please help with that.

Thank you in advance!

NOTE: I use Regular expression extractor but I cannot get value from GET url and pass it next.

In general. I need to get value of id parameter from GET url, pass it to GET url header(to the url) and pass

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXy1A.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzR1G.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLWtC.png

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract the parameter from the URL using the following regular expression:

```
id=(.*)
```

full setup of the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) just in case

[image]

and demo:

[image]

You will be able to use the extracted value as `${id}` where required. If the value has some characters which were [percent encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) you can get back the original value using [__urldecode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) like:

```
${__urldecode(${id})}
```

More information: [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri.

I am sorry, I forgot to mention. Some value from ID param is dynamically and each time is different. How to obtain it?

Comment: doesn't matter, the regular expression will extract everything starting from `id=` till the end of the URL query string

Comment: Good, then what should I put instead of some value. ?{id}? FYI: If yes, it is not working :(